# Proof that all natural numbers (except 1) have a predecessor using Well-Ordering Principle

Tags: elementary-number-theory, induction

**Context:** This question arises from the unsuccessful search for a proof (that does not use induction) of a result used to prove the equivalency of the Well-Ordering Principle ("WO") and Induction. Assume the Dedekind-Peano Axioms with addition and the following basics:

> **(A1)** $\forall x[x+1=S(x)]$
>
> **(A2)** $\forall x\forall y[x+S(y)=S(x+y)]$
>
> **(O1)** $\ \ x<y\ $ means $\ \exists z[x+z=y]$
>
> **(O2)** $\ \ x\leq y\ $ means $\ x\!=\!y\vee x\!<\!y$

In particular, the question arises on a result (labeled Theorem 1 here) used in the proof of WO implies induction:

> **Theorem 0:** The well-ordering principle implies the principle of induction.
>
> **Proof:** Let $A\!\subseteq\!\mathbb{N}$ be a set with the properties:
> *(i)* $1\!\in\!A$, and *(ii)* $k\!\in\!A$ implies $S(k)\!\in\!A$. The proof proceeds by contradiction by supposing that $A\!\neq\!\mathbb{N}$ (*i.e.*, $\mathbb{N}\backslash A$ is non-empty). According to WO, if $\mathbb{N}\backslash A$ is non-empty, then it must contain a least element, which can be denoted as $l$. By *(i)*, $l\!\neq\!1$. Therefore, from **Theorem 1**, there exists some $m\!\in\!\mathbb{N}$ such that $m\!+\!1\!=\!l$, which implies $m\!<\!l$ by (O1). It must be that $m\!\in\!A$ (since assuming otherwise would contradict $l$ being the least element of $\mathbb{N}\backslash A$). By *(ii)* and (A1), it follows that $S(m)\!=\!m\!+\!1\!=\!l\!\in\!A$. But this contradicts the assumption that $l\!\in\!\mathbb{N}\backslash A$. Hence the set $\mathbb{N}\backslash A$ must be empty, so that $A\!=\!\mathbb{N}$.

**Question:** My question is *not* on the above proof (unless there is a way to prove that result without relying on Theorem 1), but on the proof of Theorem 1 itself. I also understand how to prove Theorem 1 using induction. But since Theorem 1 is used above to *prove* induction (Theorem 0), one is obviously excluded from using induction and limited to using WO to avoid circular reasoning.

> **Theorem 1:** For all $n\!\in\!\mathbb{N}$, $n\!=\!1$ or $n$ is the successor of some $m\!\in\!\mathbb{N}$. In other words: $$\forall x\Big[\ x\!=\!1\ \vee\ \exists y[x\!=\!y\!+\!1]\ \Big]$$

However, I am at a loss as to how to prove this using just WO. I've attempted to use the method of "proof by minimum counterexample" as above, but only come as far as this:

> **Proof (incomplete):** Consider the set $B\!\subseteq\!\mathbb{N}$ defined by: $$B\equiv\{\ n\!\in\!\mathbb{N}\ :\ n\!=\!1\vee\exists m\!\in\!\mathbb{N}[n\!=\!m\!+\!1]\ \}.$$ The proof proceeds by contradiction by supposing that $B\!\neq\!\mathbb{N}$ (*i.e.*, $\mathbb{N}\backslash B$ is non-empty). According to WO, if $\mathbb{N}\backslash B$ is non-empty, then it must contain a least element, which can be denoted as $l$. It follows from the definition of $B$ that $l\!\neq\!1$ and $\neg\exists m\!\in\!\mathbb{N}[l\!=\!m\!+\!1]$.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: The set of polynomials with natural number coefficients ordered the usual way are well ordered, but don't always have a predecessor.

Comment: You might need an additional axiom: for all $n$, $1 \leq n$. (Does it follow somehow from the other axioms? Or perhaps you *define* $1$ to be the smallest element of $\mathbb{N}$, from the well-ordering?) In any case, from $1 \leq l$ and $1 \neq l$, you get $1 < l$, so $l = 1+z$ for some $z$. Then $l$ is the successor of $z$.

Comment: @DanielV: interesting. can you provide an example of a polynomial in $\mathbb{N}[x]$ that does not have a predecessor?  And, if so, why could that not be considered the initial element of the Peano system in my question (i.e., Theorem 1 allows for 1 not to have a predecessor).

Comment: @Zach: thanks for your comment! Indeed, I understand $\forall n[1\leq n]$ can be derived from Thm. 1 (along with (A1), (O1)-(2), and the commutative property of addition), so that it could not be used in the proof of Thm. 1 itself.  Which leads me to think that perhaps your are right: WO by itself is *not* equivalent to Induction.  Rather, it is WO *plus* the additional axiom that 1 is the least element of $\mathbb{N}$ that is equivalent to Induction.  I have looked far and wide, and every proof of WO$\rightarrow$Induction requires some result that can't be proved without something more.

Comment: @StephenK. A simple example of a well-ordered set with more than one element lacking a predecessor is given by the natural numbers ordered so that all even numbers come before all odd numbers.  Even numbers and odd numbers are then ordered in the usual way.  Neither $0$ nor $1$ have predecessors.  The set of pairs of natural numbers under lexicographic ordering has infinitely many elements without predecessors.

Comment: @StephenK.$2x^2$ does not have a predecessor, but also $(x \mapsto 2x^2) \ne (x \mapsto 0)$.  Also, it is very unusual to start counting at $1$, most examples of peano arithmetic start counting at $0$.

Comment: @StephenK.The general point is that there are multiple initial elements, that's what it means to not have a unique predecessor.

Comment: All, from these examples, I understand that simply providing any order relation that qualifies as a well-order relation *is not by itself* sufficient to prove induction.  However, my question above presents a specific order relation $x<y$ that means $\exists z[x+z=y]$. @Fabio's example does not seem to fit this, since $1<2$ is not defined. Thus, I am still stumped how WO (with the order relation $\leq$ defined by O1 and O2) implies induction.

Comment: @StephenK. In the first example I gave, $2 < 1$.  The order type of that well-ordered set is $\omega \cdot 2$.  One proves the equivalence of weak ordering and *strong* induction.  The equivalence of strong and weak induction holds for well-ordered sets with order type $\omega$ (like the natural numbers).

Comment: @Fabio: I am familiar with proofs of strong induction from WO as well, and they also seem to rely on a result that I can't derive solely from WO (and Peano axioms sans induction). E.g., most proofs of strong induction from WO rely on the trichotomy property of $<$.  But I have only seen the trichotomy property derived using induction (see, e.g., Elliott Mendelson's *Number Systems*' section on Natural Numbers and the Order Relation).  So the reasoning again appears circular. Are you aware of a proof of WO$\rightarrow$Strong Induction that doesn't rely on any result requiring induction?

Comment: @StephenK. I just looked at Mendelson's Theorem 4.1.  That theorem claims that the ordering relation defined by $x < y$ if and only if $(\exists z) x + z = y$ enjoys the trichotomy property.  In proving that well-ordering and strong induction are interchangeable you assume that $<$ is a strict total order.

Comment: @Fabio: You have the book! Great!  But in the derivation of 4.1 (part c in particular), induction is used.  If we are going to use Thm. 4.1c in the proof of WO$\rightarrow$Induction, then shouldn't the proof of Thm. 4.1c be free from assuming induction as a tool?  Sorry if I am just missing something. I really appreciate your feedback/comments.

Comment: @StephenK. My point is that strong induction applies to every well-ordered set, defined as a set equipped with a strict total order such that every non-empty subset has a least element.  Conversely, if strong induction applies, then the strict total order is a well-order. That I can prove without recourse to Theorem 4.1c, because that  theorem is used to show that a particular relation is a strict total order.  I know "my point" does not answer your question entirely.  I'm just trying to avoid miscommunication.  And, alas, I don't have that book; I just found the right page on line.